# How to fetch the record from database and load it to labels?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My labels: The labels are mentioned here followed by the code.

```
      <div id="valueIntroduction" class="labelarea" runat="server">   </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
       <div id="valueBacklog notice" class="labelarea">   </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
       <div id="valueReasonably complete" class="labelarea">   </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
       <div id="valueStatement of purpose" class="labelarea">   </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
       <div id="valueResume" class="labelarea"> </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
       <div id="valueTranscripts" class="labelarea">  </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
       <div id="valueGRE Official test scores" class="labelarea">   </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
       <div id="valueTOEFL or IELTS Official test scores" class="labelarea">   </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
       <div id="valueLetters of Recommendation3" class="labelarea">   </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
       <div id="valueLetters of Recommendation2" class="labelarea">   </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
       <div id="valueLetters of Recommendation1" class="labelarea"> </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
       <div id="valueSignature" class="labelarea">  </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
       <div id="valueSubject" class="labelarea">  </div>
       <div  class="line"></div>
```

This code is assigning the last record to the first label. How do I assign the correct record to correct label?

```
     if (Department.Items[0].Selected)
                {
                        firstPanel.Visible = true;
                        myLegend.InnerText = "Informatics";
                        NewComm.CommandText = "getTextHeaderINFO";

                        NewComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        NewComm.Connection = NewConn;
                        NewComm.CommandTimeout = 3000;
                        SqlDataReader results = NewComm.ExecuteReader();

                        while (results.Read())
                        {
                             Response.Write(results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString());
                             valueIntroduction.InnerHtml = results["TEXT_CONTENT"].ToString();
                        }
                 }
```

Comment: Siz S I edited my question. please have a look at it.

Comment: first id Must be without space, second what you're getting in results["TEXT_CONTENT"], use if(results.Read()) instead of  while (results.Read())

Comment: what is the sql code of the `getTextHeaderINFO` stored procedure?

Comment: @Maras: Does that really matter?  It returns records which he wants to assign to his labels.

Comment: @Jeff seeing the code of this procedure would allow me to write the exact code. we clearly see that vimal should assign values from the results using names / indexes instead of looping through all the results.

Comment: @maras... yes it is a stored procedure!!!!

Comment: @Maras: Yes, it would permit you to write the exact code.  Would that help vimal learn, though?  Or would it just permit him to copy it into place and move on, without needing to think about WHY the code was written the way it was.  I'd rather teach him to fish than give him a fish.

Comment: @Jeff sometimes example with explanation is better than spending hours trying to figure out the solution by themselves. Anyway, lets not spam here. Vimal, I know that this is stored procedure. I asked about its code

Comment: Now I got my mistake. Thanks Jeff and Maras... I really appreciate it for make me learn how to catch the fish instead of giving me a fish. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it is written now you are setting the same label's InnerHtml in every iteration of the while loop.

I would think you would be doing something more like this:

```
label1.InnerHTML = results["text_content"];
results.read()
label2.InnerHtml = results["text_content"];
```

etc.

In short, you'll need to assign the results iteratively.  It may be safer to read them into a List or a string array (in your loop) so you can verify count, but essentially you have to set each label individually.  I can't image how you could expect it to work setting a single one over and over again.

---

Now, what you SHOULD be doing, when you intend to work with HTML elements programmatically is very different from what I see here.

What you're doing here requires you to lookup HTML elements by ID, assign to their InnerHtml, and is honestly very error-prone.  It's also not a good use of C# or the .NET environment.

Use .NET labels instead.  Define them like this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="valueIntroduction" CssClass="labelarea" />
```

Then on the code behind you can access them much easier:

```
valueIntroduction.Text = "This text will show up in the valueIntroduction label";
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff.. will implement in the method which you suggested here... thanks again...

Comment: @vimal No problem.  Please remember that if an answer was helpful, you should upvote it, and you should select the most helpful answer (if any) as the solution by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call results.Read() in a loop? You should just find the one single result row in the results and put this one into the valueIntroduction.InnerHtml property.

Comment: His results seem to contain all the labels, and each read() call gets the next result.  A call to read() is interpreted as 'false' when the record cannot read further, which cleanly exits the while loop.